# Is there an expression for when you have something but cannot use it

Tags: expressions

Is there an expression for when you have something but cannot use it or it is meaningless to use it. 
For example "one has the right to strike but cannot use it".

Comment: A chimera, an illusion.

Comment: @user73381 Can you make the OP more explicit?

Comment: *useless,* *pointless,* *fruitless,* *unproductive*?

Comment: Either you have the right to strike or you don't. *You can't have it both ways*. You have the right to vote or you don't. If you possess something useless, then it's useless. It's excess baggage if it's physical. If it's emotional, then you're stuck with it. If you mean something different, please rephrase the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Fifth wheel**: "A fifth wheel is something unnecessary or useless."

Answer (score 1):

What about **Cosmetic**

> [Cosmetic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cosmetic): Decorative rather than functional.

Answer (score 1):

Their right to strike *is about as much use as owning a chocolate teapot*.

Millions of people have a right to strike but don't use it because *they'd be shooting themselves in the foot* (doing themselves more harm than good.)

The question makes perfect sense. In fact, the example given is very common.

Answer (score 0):

striking would be **an act of futility**

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/futile

futile

> 1. incapable of producing any result; ineffective; useless; not successful: Attempting to force-feed the sick horse was futile.
> 2. trifling; frivolous; unimportant.

Answer (score -1):

When you have something but cannot use it, you feel [**frustrated**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/frustrated) to not be able to use it.

> **frustrated**: having feelings of dissatisfaction or lack of fulfillment.